# Deploying Meteor App to Wampp stack

Tags: node.js, meteor, wampserver

I am wondering if you can deploy Meteor apps to a Windows based Wampp stack... Such as The Uniform Server.

I am wanting to upgrade a project to Meteor that is running on a small internal network.   I plan on using the existing mysql database.

I'm not quite sure on how deploying works.   I know it creates a tarball,  but does this just unzip into the www folder on the server?   I will also have Node installed.

I'm new to this whole node.js environment.   That's not an actual server that can be used for production is it?  It's a bit confusing.   I've only ever used wampp stacks.   I can't use anything but windows,  so Linux is outta the question for a server.

Thanks in advance.

L.

Answer (score 1):

WAMP stands for Windows, Apache, MySQL, and PHP.

1. Meteor uses Node.js, not PHP.
2. Support for other databases are coming - See the [roadmap](https://trello.com/c/6ugalZMG/54-additional-database-support)
3. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14369865/2317532)
4. NodeJS apparently works on Windows - here are the [two](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/InstallingAndRunningNodejsApplicationsWithinIISOnWindowsAreYouMad.aspx) [top](http://codetunnel.io/hosting-nodejs-applications-on-windows-server-2012-complete-with-git-deployment-and-remote-debugging-part-2/) Google links.

**tl;dr** No

Comment: As a note, most people working with Meteor uses MongoDB as data storage and Linux for the server. "I can't use anything but windows" - You can, it doesn't necessarily have to be your machine - DigitalOcean and Linode etc lets you have a Linux server up and running for $5 a month.

If you are a student, GitHub also have a freebies pack https://education.github.com/pack