# How to start NODE js on virtual sub domain, I am usgin Apache web server?

Tags: node.js, apache

Node js server has been started but not responding when I hit it from web browser

Answer (score 0):

Why would you use apache web server and node.js?

You can create a very simple web server using node.js

```
const http = require('http');

http.createServer((request, response) => {
  const { headers, method, url } = request;
  let body = [];
  request.on('error', (err) => {
    console.error(err);
  }).on('data', (chunk) => {
    body.push(chunk);
  }).on('end', () => {
    body = Buffer.concat(body).toString();
    // At this point, we have the headers, method, url and body, and can now
    // do whatever we need to in order to respond to this request.
  });
}).listen(8080); // Activates this server, listening on port 8080.
```

- taken from https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/anatomy-of-an-http-transaction/

If you're thinking on using Node.js there are plenty of framework to use, such as  Express, Hapi, Resitfy, Fastify etc...

hope that's help.

Comment: <code>
var https = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

console.log('test data');
https.createServer( function (req, res) {
  console.log('In the main page');
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end("hello world\n");
}).listen(8000);
</code>
this is my code but not showing 'In the main page' in console also 'hello world' on the web browser

Comment: I would suggest you disable apache and just use plain node.js but if you really need to use apache server for proxying your node.js app this might be useful: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html as @yudu suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You need "reverse proxy" to achieve this.

With config like:

```
ProxyPass "/"  "http://localhost:8888"
```

Replace 8888 with the real port your nodejs app listening.

Check apache's guide here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html.

Also, check another related question: [How to run nodejs application in apache server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39093366/how-to-run-nodejs-application-in-apache-server)