# Forwarding URL on CloudFlare to a specific port

Tags: node.js, apache, port, subdomain, cloudflare

I have a both apache & nodejs server, apache on port 80 and nodejs on 3001

I wanna make a url for api calls something like:

https://mywebsite..com:3001/ to https://api.mywebsite.com/ on CloudFlare

Is it possible to do? I've tried Page Rules but it didn't work.

So, how can I do it?

Thanks

Comment: You have to configure apache to route requests from port 80 to port 3001. Read about reverse proxy. Or you can serve node.js app on port 80.

Comment: if i do it on port 80, apache doesn't work

Comment: Yes, if you'd like to run apache, you have to forward requests from apache to node.js app on port 3001. It's called reverse proxy. Look at this example https://stackoverflow.com/a/39250354/6066986

Comment: @Grynets  When running a node application on a dedicated server you will need to start node as root or with sudo to allow it to use port 80. 
Indeed when Apache is running on port 80 on the same server you wont be able to start node on this port even when you are root

Comment: so i should httpd.conf for it right?
where exactly is that in Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: @BrianvanRooijen please, read my comment carefully. I've mentioned reverse proxy to nodejs app.

Comment: @Grynets my bad replied to your first comment. Reverse proxy will fix this.

Comment: @AldenWillms if it is a default install you can add an extra config to /etc/apache/sites-available and enable it with a2ensite function
https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/apache2/a2ensite.8.en.html

ensure you also enable the apache mod_proxy with a2enmod when setting up the proxy

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to configure apache to proxy api.mywebsite.com to port 3001 on your server
grepped the following example from 

`<VirtualHost *:*>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass        "/" "http://localhost:3001/"
    ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://localhost:3001/"
    ServerName api.mywebsite.com
</VirtualHost>`

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html

please ensure you you also use the right CORS settings else you wont be able to request your api from yourwebsite frontend

A different way to prevent this is just to proxy the location /api to your api

`<Location "/api/">
  ProxyPass "http://localhost:3001"
  SetEnv force-proxy-request-1.0 1
  SetEnv proxy-nokeepalive 1
</Location>`

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html

Comment: i've added the first one you wrote to /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf by changing api.mywebsite.com to my domain name, when i restarted apache, returned this

 * Restarting web server apache2                                         [fail]
 * The apache2 configtest failed.
Output of config test was:
AH00526: Syntax error on line 34 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:
Invalid command 'ProxyPreserveHost', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.

Comment: did you enable mod_proxy?

Comment: sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-proxy-html libxml2-dev -y

sudo a2enmod proxy
sudo a2enmod proxy_http
sudo a2enmod proxy_ajp
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo a2enmod deflate
sudo a2enmod headers
sudo a2enmod proxy_balancer
sudo a2enmod proxy_connect
sudo a2enmod proxy_html

Ran all of them and now apache2 on restart says:
[proxy_html:notice] [pid 9178] AH01425: I18n support in mod_proxy_html requires mod_xml2enc. Without it, non-ASCII characters in proxied pages are likely to display incorrectly.

Comment: Ok with the notice it should start. To remove the message you can also install mod_xml2enc as proposed from the apache log message.
If you are spending much time configuring it would also like to advice upgrading your ubuntu version as Ubuntu14.04 will no longer be supported starting april this year

Comment: it doesn't work, when i go to api.mysite.com:

The DNS name does not exist.
Error Code: INET_E_RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND